# Linux VM's disk went read-only = no choice but reboot?

Tags: linux, vmware, block-device, reboot, readonly

I have several Linux VMs on VMware + SAN.

### What happened

A problem occured on the SAN (failed path) so that for some time, there were I/O errors on the Linux VMs drives. When the path failover had been done, it was too late: *every Linux machine considered most of its drives as not "trustworthy" anymore, setting them as read-only devices*. The root filesystem's drives were also impacted.

### What I tried

- `mount -o rw,remount /` without success,
- `echo running > /sys/block/sda/device/state` without success,
- dug into `/sys` to find a solution without success.

### What I may have not tried

- `blockdev --setrw /dev/sda`

### Finally...

I had to reboot all my Linux VMs. The Windows VMs were fine...

### Some more info from VMware...

The problem is described [here](http://kb.vmware.com/selfservice/microsites/search.do?language=en_US&cmd=displayKC&externalId=1009465). VMware suggests to increase the Linux scsi timeout to **prevent** this problem to happen.

### The question!

However, **when the problem *does* eventually happen, is there a way to get the drives back to read-write mode?** (once the SAN is back to normal)

Comment: I have been able to get a disk back to read-write with `mount -o remount /mountpoint` on a real system. Perhaps that would work inside a VM too.

Comment: Thanks, but I already tried that, and it didn't work... I've edited my question accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

We have had this problem here a couple of times, usually due to the network going down for an extended period.  The problem is not that the file system is read-only but that the disk device itself is marked read-only.  No option here other than reboot.  Increasing the scsi timeout will work for transient glitches such as a path failover.  Won't work well for a 15-minute network outage.

Comment: Hmm, this is a Linux kernel limitation then. It deserves a bug report...

Comment: Did you try `blockdev --setrw /dev/sda`? I edited my question accordingly.

Comment: That's a new one to me.  Hopefully I'll never see the problem again but I'll try this when it does happen.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

From the man of `mount` :

```
   errors={continue|remount-ro|panic}
              Define the behavior  when  an  error  is  encountered.   (Either
              ignore  errors  and  just mark the filesystem erroneous and con‐
              tinue, or remount the filesystem read-only, or  panic  and  halt
              the  system.)   The default is set in the filesystem superblock,
              and can be changed using tune2fs(8).
```

So you should mount your VM with the `continue` option instead of `remount-ro`.

```
mount -o errors=continue
mount -o remount
```

Answer (score 1):

I've had this happen on a RHEL system when rebooting/re-configuring the attached SAN. What worked for me was to deactivate the volume group and LVM, and then reactivate it.

`vgchange -a n /vg_group_name`
`lvchange -a n /lvm_group_name`

Then you must reactivate them.

`vgchange -a y /vg_group_name`
`lvchange -a y /lvm_group_name`

Then just try and remount everything with a `mount -a`.

Comment: Probably doesn't work for the root `/` filesystem, which was the problematic fs in my case...

Comment: Not sure. Hopefully this will help someone fighting with production SAN issues like I have been.

Answer (score 0):

Having run test cases using a test VM running on an NFS datastore that I've been intentionally disabling, I haven't found anything that worked. The *blockdev* command didn't work, and the vg / lv commands do refuse to work on a mounted root `/` system.

At this point, the best option seems to be to set `errors=panic` in */etc/fstab*so the VM just hard fails.